# why isnt the event object in the window object prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, events, window, prototype

One thing I'm struggling to understand in my learning is the concept of the element and event objects. I understand JavaScript comes with a global window object and there are four other built in objects, Math, String,Array,Date. Am I correct in saying the document object is a property of the global window object ? How about the document Element Object and the Event Object, i can find the event object at all on the Window prototype. How does the event object come about? is it inherited when an event occurs?

Comment: Well Event is an interface unless you are referring to something else. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: Properties of [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). `document` usually is short for `window.document`.

Answer (score 0):

> According to w3schools website:
> [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp#:~:text=HTML%20DOM%20events%20allow%20JavaScript,a%20user%20clicks%20a%20button](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp#:%7E:text=HTML%20DOM%20events%20allow%20JavaScript,a%20user%20clicks%20a%20button)).
> “HTML DOM events allow JavaScript to register different event handlers on elements in an HTML document. Events are normally used in combination with functions, and the function will not be executed before the event occurs.”

I think you could better understand the concept of events with the code that I posted. In that code, if you click the button, in the console you can find the properties of “click or MouseEvent” event.

For using that properties, I defined a “div” that when you click everywhere in that div, you find an alert that say the position of your click. I used “clientX” and “clientY” properties of "click" event.

```js
function clickFunc(inp) {
    console.log(inp);
    
}

function mousePlace(inp2) {
    posX = inp2.clientX;
    posY = inp2.clientY;
    alert("x:"+posX+"y:"+posY);
}
```

```css
.bg-red {
    background-color: rgb(200,15,10);
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 2px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, illum, reiciendis! Perspiciatis corporis, iste dolore excepturi ipsa animi. Saepe assumenda quae, expedita facilis rerum provident vero illum reprehenderit consequatur suscipit illo. Qui atque ab sit tempore, laboriosam, officiis quisquam, cum harum libero rem architecto ipsam molestias accusantium quasi delectus? Quidem.</p>
       
       <button onclick="clickFunc(event)">click me</button>
   </div>
   
   <div class="bg-red" onclick="mousePlace(event)">
       
   </div>
    
    
<script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```